# Triggers in Azure devops with many branches in repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

On a migration from gitlab to azure, we need to specify triggers. I have a pipeline on my main (azure-pipelines.yml) which describes the pipeline, I have a trigger condition

```
trigger:
  - none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
```

This is purely to make sure that after the merge to main has happened, the  pipeline is triggered.
However, if I create any feature to this repo, I create a new branch ( featureX) from master and it will have the same `azure-pipelines.yml` file.  On this branch, I would like the SW to be built for every commit I do to that branch ( featureX). So it makes sense to have the trigger in the  branch ( featureX) as follows:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
```

Now when the merge is ready, is it a best practise to delete the pipeline file from the featureBranch or do we change the trigger in the yml file of featureBranch?

Or is it handled in a way which I did not mention here?

Comment: Please be aware that `pr` blocks do not apply to Azure Repos, only external Git providers like GitHub. If you want builds to run as part of PRs, use branch policies with validation builds.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to trigger a build for every PR and for any feature branches?
If I understand that correctly, keep a single `azure-pipelines.yml` file and just add a branch trigger:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/*
 pr:
   branches:
     include:
     - main
```